# MySQL Parameterized Query using Like

Tags: mysql

I want to run a query like this in MySQL:

```
select * from table where column1 like '%searchdata%'
```

But I want to use a parameter to pass in the search text. Is this possible? This doesn't seem to work:

```
select * from table where column1 like '%?Parameter%'
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `%` symbols need to be inside the parameter value, so it's something more like:

```
select * from table where column1 like ?;
```

And then you set the parameter to:

```
%searchText%
```

Comment: Ahh, the sound of my hand hitting my forehead.